# Predicting with ridge model underestimating effect size

Tags: predictive-models, ridge-regression

To my understanding ridge minimizes the beta's under a penalty (lambda) to avoid over-fitting, as betas closer to zero are more realistic.

This process of minimizing beta's leads in turn to smaller, beta's close to zero and therefore zero biased predicted Y. When predicting from X with a ridge model using the same input data the predicted Y is closer to zero than one might expect.

For example: When drawing a regression line Y_real , Y_predicted,  The slope is closer to 0.

Is there any literature available on 'correcting' the zero biased estimated beta's that the ridge produces? As of now, my model seems to underestimate the
Y, and therefore a bad predictor of Y.

Comment: How are you determining the ridge penalty parameter, and are you eveluating your model on a properly held out data set?

Comment: You might use an intercept term fixed at full scale. Thus fit $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{1} \beta_1 +  \mathbf{X}\beta_{others}$ using $\beta_1=\overline{y}$. (or in another way, substract the mean $\overline{y}$ from the vector $y$ before doing the ridge model) (this is a bit more difficult if the mean of X is not zero)

Comment: @MatthewDrury  The ridge penalty parameter is determined by cross validation. The dataset is not an out dataset. Prediction evaluation is done using data not used for prediction, but within the same dataset.